# Prove that $x^2+I=-1+I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic, ideals

I have given an ideal $I=\{(x^2+1)\cdot p(x)|p(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]\}$ which is an ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$. I have to prove that $x^2+I=-1+I$ holds in $\mathbb{R}[x]/I$.

I think, that I is also a principal ideal and in the university lecture we discussed the following:

Let $K[x]$ be a ring and $(P(x))$ a principal ideal, then $K[x]/P(x)$ is a quotient ring and the following holds:

$A(x)\equiv B(x) \mod P(x) \Leftrightarrow P(x)|A(x)-B(x)$ as well as $A(x)\equiv B(x) \land C(x)\equiv D(x)\mod P(x)\implies A(x)+(C(x)\equiv B(x)+D(x)\mod P(x)$

I used this to derive:

$x^2+1|x^2-(-1)\Leftrightarrow x^2\equiv -1$ and also
$x^2\equiv -1 \land I\equiv I\implies x^2+I\equiv -1+I$ and because $\mathbb{R}[x]/I$ is a quotient ring, $x^2+I=-1+I$ hold as well.

Can anybody check whether this reasing is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by $x^2 + I = -1 + I$ ? that for any $i \in I, x^2 + i = -1 + i$ ? If so, you may take a $i \in I$, and since $x^2 + 1 = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}[X]/I$ (because $x^2 + 1 \in I$), you add $i$ to both sides a and it concludes your problem.

Comment: This is what you did in your proof and yes $I$ is a principal ideal by definition ($I = (x^2 + 1)\mathbb{R}[X])$)

Comment: Also, for your culture, what interesting property does $X$ satisfy in $\mathbb{R}[X]/I$ ? and can you draw a parallel with a certain element of a known field ?

Comment: @Beleth I think $x^2 + I = -1 + I$ is meant to say that for all $i \in I$, there exists a $j \in I$ such that $x^2 + i = -1 + j$. Or at least that's the meaning I know of.

Comment: @Beleth   Bruno is correct. The question poster has nothing to be blamed. This notation is standard.

Comment: (And this comment to the asker): In a quotient ring $R/I$, an element $r+I$ (where $r\in R$) is in fact a subset of $R$: $r+I\overset{\text{def}}{=}\{r+x:\ x\in I\}$. Two elements in quotient ring are equal when they are equal as sets. Now can you conclude by yourself what is a necessary and sufficient condition for $r_1+I=r_2+I$?  (answer: $r_1-r_2\in I$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, $I = (X^2+1)\mathbb{R}[X]$ so it is a [principal ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal) by definition.

*As a remark, all ideals of $\mathbb{R}[X]$ are principal (consider the monic polynomial $P$ of smallest degree in the ideal, which is unique by construction, and use the Euclidean division to prove that the ideal is equal to $P\mathbb{R}[X]$). We say that $\mathbb{R}[X]$ is a [principal ideal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain) (aka a PID).*

Your question is whether $X^2+I = -1 + I$ holds in $\mathbb{R}[X]/I$. Be careful with the fact that with conventional notations, $X^2+I$ usually denotes a set, that of all polynomials of $I$ plus $X^2$.
If the question is to be understood as the fact that this holds for all polynomials in $I$, this is equivalent to the fact that $X^2=-1$ in $\mathbb{R}[X]/I$ (take $0\in I$ for instance).

And this equality follows directly from the definition of a [quotient ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring): $A = B$ in $\mathbb{R}[X]/I$ if and only if $A-B\in I$. In our case, since $I = (X^2+1)\mathbb{R}[X]$, the condition becomes $(X^2+1)| A-B$, which is trivially true with $A=X^2$ and $B=-1$.

As a remark, $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)$ formally defines [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Formal_construction).

Regarding your reasoning now,

1. the second property you list is wrong, take for example $A=1, B=X, C=X+1, D=1$ (where $B\wedge C=1)$,
2. $X^2\equiv-1\wedge I\equiv I$ is wrong as well: $-1\wedge I = -1$ (and $X^2\equiv I$ does not hold for all polynomials $I$ of the ideal).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in short: Yes, your reasoning is correct.

If $I \subset R$ is an ideal and $r_1,r_2 \in R$ are elements of $R$, we have $$
r_1+I = r_2+I \iff r_1-r_2 \in I
$$
In this case, it means we have $X^2+I = -1+I \iff X^2+1 \in I$ which is obviously true.

Comment: this is not his reasoning

Comment: $X^2+1 \in I$ is equivalent to saying $X^2+1 \,\vert\, X^2-(-1)$.

Comment: I agree, but his reasoning consists in using the second fact he listed (after the definition of the modulo).